# How to save cell value(image) of a vertical grid control (devexpress) to sql database?

Tags: c#, image, save, devexpress

I have a vgridcontrol of devexpress that contain a row for save user profile picture. How do I save images to the database?

When this code runs:

```
Image image = vgridcontrol.getcellvalue(row_photo, 0) as Image;
```

Image is null. Any ideas?

Comment: please show what you have tried

Comment: Image image=vgridcontrol.getcellvalue(row_photo,0) as Image ; but image =null why?

Comment: if you add code "var imageUnknown=vgridcontrol.getcellvalue(row_photo,0)" and set a breakpoint there: what's the type of the imageUnknown? You can see it in watch window.

Answer (score 0):

Images are stored in a byte arrays, so you can simply save your byte array to SQL without converting to `Image`.

If you want to get the `Image` from byte array then you can get it from `MemoryStream` which is filled by your byte array:

```cs
var byteImage = (byte[])vGridControl1.GetCellValue(row_photo, 0);

if (byteImage == null)
    return;

using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(byteImage))
{
    var image = Image.FromStream(memoryStream);

    //Do whatever you want with your image.
}
```